# cmd cURL not working the same as chrome dev tools fetch

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch, google-chrome-devtools

I have been trying to use cmd curl to get data, and the fetch command works in chrome dev tools console, but it doesn't return the right result with cmd, I used the copy as cURL function in dev tools, but it returns different results. The weird thing is when I used copy as PowerShell and used the Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell 7, it got the correct response. The website I am running the dev tools from is https://homeaccess.saisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fhomeaccess. Thanks for any feedback.

```js
//The "copy as fetch" which works in dev tools console
fetch("https://homeaccess.saisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fHomeAccess%2f", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
  },
  "referrer": "https://homeaccess.saisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fHomeAccess%2f",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "__RequestVerificationToken=XM3fJKbbs7QjfVKVPFAcltMmoFRecsbXPcWbcNrop1_R4eHIHGEaZKo65p9UUpqOBTJymC20mJGKaF2P4zVM1urYf2Fv5mPHQf4q5yEw3j41&SCKTY00328510CustomEnabled=False&SCKTY00436568CustomEnabled=False&Database=10&VerificationOption=UsernamePassword&LogOnDetails.UserName=55555&tempUN=&tempPW=&LogOnDetails.Password=88888888",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
//and the "copy as cURL" which doesnt return correct response in cmd
curl "https://homeaccess.saisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=^%^2fHomeAccess^%^2f" ^
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" ^
  -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" ^
  -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" ^
  -H "Origin: https://homeaccess.saisd.org" ^
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ^
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36" ^
  -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-User: ?1" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Dest: document" ^
  -H "Referer: https://homeaccess.saisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=^%^2fHomeAccess^%^2f" ^
  -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9" ^
  -H "Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1480406019.1587230747; SPIHACSiteCode=; __RequestVerificationToken_L0hvbWVBY2Nlc3M1=XncgYsOz0wLk4SEPgKwYPP23lLLCuC0uUyp6IE3BjuAy8QarbyT6_Unape_o9HP8bd3MHpcdkQr8zE3SIXedrqCNGwQEuKPlNrjqM5VFb5M1; ASP.NET_SessionId=240ee2yydcofxchrrsnqgshr" ^
  --data-raw "__RequestVerificationToken=XM3fJKbbs7QjfVKVPFAcltMmoFRecsbXPcWbcNrop1_R4eHIHGEaZKo65p9UUpqOBTJymC20mJGKaF2P4zVM1urYf2Fv5mPHQf4q5yEw3j41^&SCKTY00328510CustomEnabled=False^&SCKTY00436568CustomEnabled=False^&Database=10^&VerificationOption=UsernamePassword^&LogOnDetails.UserName=55555^&tempUN=^&tempPW=^&LogOnDetails.Password=88888888" ^
  --compressed
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in Chrome: try replacing `^&` with `&` inside the last string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank you very much, changing ^& to & on the last line made it work perfectly, now my functional code is this.

```js
curl "https://homeaccess.saisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=^%^2fHomeAccess^%^2f" ^
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" ^
  -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" ^
  -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" ^
  -H "Origin: https://homeaccess.saisd.org" ^
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ^
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36" ^
  -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-User: ?1" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Dest: document" ^
  -H "Referer: https://homeaccess.saisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=^%^2fHomeAccess^%^2f" ^
  -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9" ^
  -H "Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1480406019.1587230747; SPIHACSiteCode=; __RequestVerificationToken_L0hvbWVBY2Nlc3M1=XncgYsOz0wLk4SEPgKwYPP23lLLCuC0uUyp6IE3BjuAy8QarbyT6_Unape_o9HP8bd3MHpcdkQr8zE3SIXedrqCNGwQEuKPlNrjqM5VFb5M1; ASP.NET_SessionId=240ee2yydcofxchrrsnqgshr" ^
  --data-raw "__RequestVerificationToken=XM3fJKbbs7QjfVKVPFAcltMmoFRecsbXPcWbcNrop1_R4eHIHGEaZKo65p9UUpqOBTJymC20mJGKaF2P4zVM1urYf2Fv5mPHQf4q5yEw3j41&SCKTY00328510CustomEnabled=False&SCKTY00436568CustomEnabled=False&Database=10&VerificationOption=UsernamePassword&LogOnDetails.UserName=55555&tempUN=&tempPW=&LogOnDetails.Password=88888888"
```